# Unable to use custom Mapreduce jar files in Cosmos

Tags: mapreduce, fiware, fiware-cosmos

I created my own Mapreduce jar file and tested in the Cosmos' [old Hadoop cluster](http://cosmos.lab.fiware.org) successfully using the HDFS shell commands. The next step was to test the same jar in the new cluster, so I uploaded it to the 
[new cluster's HDFS](http://storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org), to my home folder (user/my.username).

When I try to start a Mapreduce job using the curl post below,

```
curl -X POST "http://computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:12000/tidoop/v1/user/my.username/jobs" -d '{"jar":"dt.jar","class_name":"DistanceTest","lib_jars":"dt.jar","input":"input","output":"output"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I get:

> {"success":"false","error":255}

I tried different path values for the jar and I get the same result. Do I have to upload my jar to somewhere else or am I missing some necessary steps?

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the code, already fixed in the global instance of FIWARE Lab.

I've tested this:

```
$ curl -X POST "http://computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:12000/tidoop/v1/user/myuser/jobs" -d '{"jar":"mrjars/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar","class_name":"wordcount","lib_jars":"mrjars/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar","input":"testdir","output":"outputdir"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: mytoken"
{"success":"true","job_id": "job_1460639183882_0016"}
```

Please observe in this case, `mrjars/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar` is a relative path under `hdfs:///user/myuser`. Always use relative paths with this opeartion.

```
$ curl -X GET "http://storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/myuser/mrjars?op=liststatus&user.name=myuser" -H "X-Auth-Token: mytoken"
{"FileStatuses":{"FileStatus":[{"pathSuffix":"hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar","type":"FILE","length":270283,"owner":"myuser","group":"myuser","permission":"644","accessTime":1464702215233,"modificationTime":1464702215479,"blockSize":134217728,"replication":3}]}}
```

The result:

```
$ curl -X GET "http://storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/myuser/outputdir?op=liststatus&user.name=myuser" -H "X-Auth-Token: mytoken"
{"FileStatuses":{"FileStatus":[{"pathSuffix":"_SUCCESS","type":"FILE","length":0,"owner":"myuser","group":"myuser","permission":"644","accessTime":1464706333691,"modificationTime":1464706333706,"blockSize":134217728,"replication":3},{"pathSuffix":"part-r-00000","type":"FILE","length":128,"owner":"myuser","group":"myuser","permission":"644","accessTime":1464706333264,"modificationTime":1464706333460,"blockSize":134217728,"replication":3}]}}
```

I'll upload the fix to the Cosmos repo in GitHub ASAP.

Comment: This time, I get `{"success":"false","error":1}`. Is there a Hadoop version difference between the old and the new clusters or am I missing something? [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19150764/Cosmos_test.zip) is the jar file and the sample input I use for testing.